# Angular 2 and karma-jasmine unit test case to open modal on click of link

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to test that on click of link, modal should open.

I have written following test in `spec.ts file`

```
describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
  let comp:    NavbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
  let de:      DebugElement;
  let el:      HTMLElement;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        NavbarComponent
      ],
        imports: [ ng2Bootstrap.Ng2BootstrapModule.forRoot() ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance; 
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('nav'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
  });
  it('signin should open modal', fakeAsync(() => {
    var signin = <HTMLElement>el.getElementsByClassName("signin-link")[0];
    signin.click();
    tick();
    var temp =<HTMLElement>el.getElementsByClassName("signinmodal")[0];
    expect(["block"]).toContain(temp.style.display);
  }));
```

I am using fakeasync and tick() as shown in the [angular2 test guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#fake-async)

But the above test always fails as `Expected [ 'block' ] to contain ''.`

Here is the template code

```
<li><a href="#" class="signin-link" (click)="signinmodal.show()" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".signinmodal">Signin</a></li>

<div class="modal signinmodal" bsModal #signinmodal="bs-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
      ...
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Edit

I also tried using their click simulator,as described in [their test guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#trigger-event-handler)

> The click() helper function is not one of the Angular testing
>   utilities. It's a function defined in this guide's sample code. All of
>   the sample tests use it. If you like it, add it to your own collection
>   of helpers.

```
export const ButtonClickEvents = {
   left:  { button: 0 },
   right: { button: 2 }
};
export function click(el: DebugElement | HTMLElement, eventObj: any = ButtonClickEvents.left): void {
  if (el instanceof HTMLElement) {
    el.click();
  } else {
    el.triggerEventHandler('click', eventObj);
  }
}
```

and then calling `click(signin)` instead of `signin.click()`. But still the test failed.

Comment: In the test guide, they call `fixture.detectChanges();`

Comment: I had tried calling it before and after tick, but somehow the test always fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**
I've taken a minimum working example of ng2-bootstrap and tried to test it using jasmine unit tests, and I don't think it's going to be possible. The unit tests run inside a cut-down browser window without access to the full style sheet, external dependencies (like bootstrap) etc. These tests are designed to test the logic of your component, rather than the rendering and display of a template.

If you want to test this level of ui interaction, you're best of putting it in an E2E test and then using protractor. Then you will have an entire, runnable browser instance and there ng2-bootstrap should work as expected.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/e2e

**Initial answer:**

Sorry to ask a potentially dumb question, but isn't your expect the wrong way round? Shouldn't it be:

`expect(temp.style.display).toContain("block");`

Although that probably won't resolve the issue, it's important to note that `expect` should operate on the item under test, and in certain scenarios (I'm not sure if this is one of them) can be responsible for resolving promises.

To troubleshoot the *actual* problem, maybe you should first verify that the click of the sign-in modal is working and that you're actually finding all of the elements on the page. It can sometimes occur that no errors are thrown, but the element isn't found.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have corrected the `expect` code. `verify that the click of the sign-in modal is working and that you're actually finding all of the elements on the page` - yes the actual modal pops up on click of signin link.

Comment: How are you binding `style: display;' onto the template?

Comment: I am using the `ModalModule` from ng2-bootstrap library. It adds the `block` display when the modal opens up. Let me update the template code as well in question

Comment: And you're sure that it adds a `style="display: block;"`? I think it might be a good idea to pivot the test to rather achieve the end in a different way? Are you just trying to verify that the modal popup is visible?

Comment: I checked in the chrome. It toggles between `block` and `none`. I am just to verify if the modal popup is visible. Is there any other way to check for the visibility of an element other than css?